# UICollectionView displays cells incorrectly after frame change

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I noticed that if I change the frame of a UICollectionView (e.g. when the toggling the in-call status bar), the collection view doesn't update its cells properly for its new frame. It's probably easiest to see in a short video:

http://cl.ly/2t2Y2A3A2w1D/CollectionViewTest.mov

The source files for that simple test are here:

http://cl.ly/0S0A360B3I3Q/CollectionViewTest.zip

It doesn't seem to matter whether I use UICollectionViewController or UIViewController. Has anyone seen this? Am I missing something? The only workaround I've found is to call reloadData on the collection view in the view controller's viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews which works but is far from ideal when the collection view's frame is being affected by a user drag since reloadData is called many times and results in very sluggish UI updates while the user is dragging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem, where my `UICollectionView`'s `frame` changed and unless I call `reloadData` it got stuck in the same spot without moving with the `CollectionView`.

I've fixed it by adding this to my CollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}
```

Worked nicely.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't heard of that and it does seem to do the trick. It's too bad though that there are some animation glitches. Here's a quick video to see what I mean: http://cl.ly/3F173f173B3Q/CollectionViewTest.mov And for anyone interested here are the source files for that: http://cl.ly/1c252y1J182h/CollectionViewTest.zip Anyhow, I think this is probably the technique that Apple intends so I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I just needed to resize the collection view frame so that a menu could show below it and the user could still scroll up far enough that the menu doesn't cover the cells at the bottom.

Changing the content inset worked for me.

```
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, rect.size.height+8, 0);
```

I couldn't get changing the frame of the collection view to work without reloading the data, which would screw up cells that were already selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your UICollectionViewController register for the UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification, and reloadData in the selector. That way, you'll only be reloading the data when the status bar changes frame.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callCameIn:) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)callCameIn:(NSNotification *) aNote {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem though in my case is that the collection view's frame can also be changed by the user dragging. And so I could reloadData continuously via viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews but as I mentioned that makes the UI sluggish during the drag -- understandably so with all those reloads going on. That's why I'm hoping I'm either doing something wrong (i.e. this isn't a UICollectionView bug) or there's some other workaround that doesn't have a noticeable performance hit.